# Finding the Largest and Smallest Integers In A Set- Basic

Tags: c++, integer

I'm kind of on the right track, however my output is not quite right. The program asks for the number of integers you have and then it asks for those numbers. For an example is says please enter the number of integers, you can put 3. And then you enter 3 numbers. I can't use arrays because I am a beginner student and we have not learned those yet. Using count is the only way that allows me to input integers. What do I need to add to my program? Again I am a general computer science student so I can't use anything advanced. I used include iostream, namespace int main and all that you just cant see it

```
int data;
int num;
int count=0;
int max=0;

do
{
cout<<"Enter the number of intergers"<<endl;
cin>>num;


while (count<num) 
{ 
    cout<<"Please enter a number"<<endl;
    cin>>data;
    count++;

    if (data<min)
    { 
        min=data;
    }

    if (data>max)
    {
        max=data;
    }
}


cout<<"Smallest integer:"<<min<<endl;
cout<<"Largest integer:"<<max<<endl;


cout<<"Would you like to continue?"<<endl;
cin>>ans;


} while ((ans=='y')||(ans=='Y'));
```

return 0;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out something like this:

```
int data;
int num;
int max=0, min = 1000000;

cout<<"Enter the number of intergers"<<endl;
cin>>num;

for (int count = 0; count < num; ++count)
{ 
    cout<<"Please enter number #" << count <<endl;
    cin>>data;

    if (data<min)
    { 
        min = data;
    }
    if (data>max)
    {
        max = data;
    }
}

cout<<"The smallest number:"<<min<<endl;
cout<<"The largest number:"<<max<<endl;
```

Comment: It may be better to have `min = INT_MAX` rather than an arbitrary large number. Just need to `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: @Desolator I initilaized my variables to a large number because we can't use INT_MAX & yet, but when the loop asks me do I want to continue I say yes and it asks for the number of integers and then it gives me the same output as the previous set. For an example I'll enter 3 integers, 21 22 & 23, and it'll say largest: 23 smallest:21 but when I say yes I want to continue it will give me 23 & 21 again. I used a do while to be able to continue  with the while condition as ((ans=='y') or (ans=='Y'))

Comment: @Ka112324 I think you just missed the initialization *at begging of do-while loop*. If you initialized your variables at beginning of `main()` then it will display each time the previous result `do { min = 1000000; max = 0; ...`

Comment: @Desolator I changed initialization to min=999999 and max=-999999 because that is what my professor said, but are you saying put a condition next to do?

Comment: @Ka112324 No. I mean to initialize these variables at begging of loop: `do { min = 9999999; max = -9999999; ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use two temporal variables to store the smallest-so-far and biggest-so-far numbers. On each loop iteration, you check if need to update them.
I don't want to put any code... it is your assignment ;-)

Comment: @dunbar 
I get what you are saying and I know how to set up a temp variable, but I'm not sure with my code. Like would it be Temp=min and then maybe min=max , and then max=Temp

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is the way to do this correct but to be more explicit you may have to update the smallest or the biggest number. For example; give the computer 5 then 4.. Your program prints 4 as a biggest number. However if you update "max" by using any other temporary int, it will give the right number .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your condition is wrong, it should be `while( count < num)`, since `count` starts at 0. Now, if you want the quick n' dirty way, simply initialize two variables, min and max to the minimum and maximum values an `int` can hold. Check the input via comparisons for each variable and update as needed.